# Trying to convert a .sql file into an .mdb access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an sql file I made for my database class and I'm having problems trying to turn the sql file with create table and insert statements to be converted into an .mdb access database. I've been googleing for hours and can't find a solution please help.

Comment: So the file you currently have contains CREATE TABLE statements and so on? If so, then does it use a particular dialect of SQL (e.g., SQL Server, MySQL, ...)?

Comment: it uses SQLplus wasn't sure if that mattered much.

Comment: Oracle and Access use different SQL dialects.  It matters a great deal.

Comment: So is it not possible? I'm having trouble trying to find a program that can do something like this.

Comment: You will have to translate Oracle SQL to Access.  It might be faster to load the tables into an Oracle instance and then import them into Access using ODBC ... the ODBC driver would translate Oracle data types to Access-compatible types.

Answer (score 0):

Normaly you export Access Database to SQL Server, not inverse.

If you want really to import SQL file into Access, you must do
it step by step.

First you use the table creation instructions in the SQL file.

In Access 2007, you can use Data Definition Query to create a table:

## Table Creation:

```
CREATE Table tblWebsites (
  ID COUNTER CONSTRAINT PrimaryKey PRIMARY KEY,
  url varchar(255) NULL,
  description varchar(255) NULL
) ;
```

## Data Insertion, must be run line by line:

```
INSERT INTO tblWebsites (url, description) VALUES ('http://www.example.com/', 'Example');
```

You can do this by a VBA function reading the SQL file and handle it line per line by:

```
Dim strSQL
strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblWebsites (url, description) VALUES ('http://www.example.com/', 'Example');"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

It's doable, but the work is not small.

Comment: Thank you for this! and I've been working really hard on the site so really want to get a certain database for this project.